# Using THREE.ShaderMaterial in the Forge Viewer causes selection issues

Tags: three.js, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative

**I have created a Github repository and test page to demonstrate this issue.**

**Live Demo: https://throw-away-97743.github.io/ForgeViewerTests/material-selection-test.html**

**Repository: https://github.com/throw-away-97743/ForgeViewerTests**

After applying a custom `THREE.ShaderMaterial` to a model in the Forge viewer (version 7.90.0), the following bugs are noticed:

1. Group selection does not work correctly (Ctrl+Left Click and drag). Almost 100% of the time, the meshes you attempted to select will not be selected.

[image: Group selection is not working]

2. Hovering over a particular mesh with the cursor will sometimes highlight completely different meshes in the scene.

[image: Hover highlight glitches]

3. Selecting a single mesh will cause what appears to be Z-fighting/stitching between the ShaderMaterial and the selection material. How could this happen on a single mesh? Note: the Selection Mode must be set to "Leaf Object" or "Last Object" to trigger the Z-fighting.

[image: Z-fighting/stitching]

I would expect using a `THREE.ShaderMaterial` would have no issues in the Forge Viewer, since the Viewer's `StandardSurface` and `Prism` materials are based on `THREE.ShaderMaterial`. However, this is not the case.

### The following is the snippet of code used to create the ShaderMaterial. Please visit the live demo using the link near the top of the question, or view the bottom of this question for the entire code.

```
const customMaterial = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
    vertexShader: `#include <pack_normals>\nvoid main() {\ngl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(position.xyz, 1.0);\n}`,
    fragmentShader: `#include <id_decl_frag>\nuniform vec3 color;\nvoid main() {\ngl_FragColor = vec4(color, 1.0);\n#include <final_frag>\n}`,
    uniforms: {color: {type: 'v3', value: new THREE.Vector3(0.5, 0, 0)}}
});
customMaterial.needsUpdate = true;
```

### Edit: because some commenters are asking for the full code listed in the repository, please see the below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">
<head>
    <title>ShaderMaterial Selection Bug</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <style>
        *:not(button) {
            margin: 0;
            border: 0;
            padding: 0;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            color: inherit;
            font-family: inherit;
            font-size: inherit;
            text-align: left;
        }

        button {
            cursor: pointer;
            padding: 10px 10px;
            border-radius: 10px;
        }

        html, body {
            height: 100%;
        }

        body {
            background-color: rgb(23, 25, 29);
            color: rgb(244, 244, 246);
            font-size: 14px;
        }

        body,
        input,
        button {
            font-family: 'Segoe UI', 'Lucida Grande', -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Liberation Sans', sans-serif;
        }

        table {
            width: 100%;
            table-layout: auto;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            border-spacing: 0;
            empty-cells: show;
        }

        td, th {
            vertical-align: middle;
            text-align: center;
        }
    </style>
    <!--<script src="/forge/viewer3D.js"></script>-->
    <script src="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/derivativeservice/v2/viewers/viewer3D.min.js?v=7.90.0"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/derivativeservice/v2/viewers/style.css?v=7.90.0"/>
</head>
<body style="overflow:hidden;">
<div style="height:40px;line-height:40px;text-align:center;font-weight:bold;font-size:18px;white-space:nowrap;">
    Forge Viewer &amp; THREE.ShaderMaterial Selection/Highlighting/Visual Artifacts Example
</div>
<div style="position:relative;margin:0 auto;max-width:100%;height:calc(100% - (40px + 310px));background-color:#ffffff;">
    <div id="ViewerContainerDiv" style="position:absolute;width:100%;height:100%;"></div>
</div>
<div style="height:310px;padding:10px 10px 0 10px;">
    <table style="width:0.01%;margin:0 auto;">
        <tr>
            <td style="vertical-align:top;padding:0 20px 0 0;">
                <div style="width:380px;text-align:justify;font-size:12px;">
                    This page demonstrates how, after applying a custom <b>THREE.ShaderMaterial</b> to a model in the Forge viewer (<b>version 7.90.0</b>), the following bugs are noticed:<br/><br/>
                    1. Group selection does not work correctly (Ctrl+Left Click and drag). Almost 100% of the time, the meshes you attempted to select will not be selected.
                    <a href="/img/selectionbug1.png" target="_blank">click to view screenshot</a><br/><br/>
                    2. Hovering over a particular mesh with the cursor will sometimes highlight completely different meshes in the scene.
                    <a href="/img/selectionbug2.png" target="_blank">click to view screenshot</a><br/><br/>
                    3. Selecting a single mesh will cause what appears to be Z-fighting/stitching between the ShaderMaterial and the selection material. How could this happen on a single mesh?
                    <b>Note: the Selection Mode must be set to "Leaf Object" or "Last Object" to trigger the Z-fighting.</b>
                    <a href="/img/selectionbug3.png" target="_blank">click to view screenshot</a>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td style="vertical-align:top;padding-right:20px;">
                <button id="LmvMaterialButton" style="width:200px;">
                    Click to apply<br/><b>LMVMeshPhongMaterial</b><br/>to the scene (viewer default)
                </button>
            </td>
            <td style="vertical-align:top;">
                <button id="ShaderMaterialButton" style="width:180px;">
                    Click to apply a custom<br/><b>THREE.ShaderMaterial</b><br/>to the scene
                </button>
                <div style="text-align:center;margin-top:5px;">
                    &uArr;<br/><span style="font-size:12px;">Click this button<br/>to activate the bugs.</span>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<!--
-->
<script>
    /**
     * @param {any} input
     * @return {boolean}
     */
    function __isFunction(input) {
        return typeof input === "function";
    }

    /**
     * @param {any} input
     * @return {boolean}
     */
    function __isIterable(input) {
        return typeof (input?.[Symbol.iterator]) === "function";
    }

    /**
     * @param {any} input
     * @return {boolean}
     */
    function __isObject(input) {
        return input !== null && typeof input === "object" && !__isIterable(input);
    }

    function __isString(input) {
        return typeof (input) === "string";
    }

    function __isNumber(input) {
        return typeof (input) === "number";
    }

    /**
     * @param {?string} [msg]
     */
    function __err(msg) {
        throw new Error(msg ?? "");
    }

    /**
     * @param {?number} [min]
     * @param {?number} [max]
     */
    function __randomInt(min, max) {
        min ??= 1000000000000000;
        max ??= 9007199254740991;
        min <= max || __err("min must be less than or equal to max.");
        return Math.floor((Math.random() * ((max - min) + 1)) + min);
    }
</script>
<script>
    const profileSettings =/**@type{ProfileSettings}*/{
        name: "mySettings",
        settings: {
            ambientShadows: false,
            antialiasing: false,
            groundReflection: false,
            groundShadow: false,
            reverseMouseZoomDir: true
        },
        extensions: {
            load: ["Autodesk.ViewCubeUi"],
            unload: []
        }
    };
    Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer({env: "Local"}, function () {
        const viewerContainerDiv = document.getElementById("ViewerContainerDiv");
        const constructorOptions = {
            addFooter: undefined,
            canvasConfig: undefined,
            containerLayerOrder: undefined,
            defaultModelStructureTitle: undefined,
            disabledExtensions: undefined,
            docStructureConfig: undefined,
            heightAdjustment: undefined,
            i18nOpts: undefined,
            left: undefined,
            loaderExtensions: undefined,
            localizeTitle: undefined,
            localStoragePrefix: undefined,
            marginTop: undefined,
            modelBrowserExcludeRoot: false,
            modelBrowserStartCollapsed: true,
            navToolsConfig: undefined,
            screenModeDelegate: undefined,
            scrollEaseCurve: undefined,
            scrollEaseSpeed: undefined,
            startOnInitialize: undefined,
            theme: undefined,
            viewerVersion: undefined,
            extensions: undefined,
            region: undefined
        };
        const viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.GuiViewer3D(viewerContainerDiv, constructorOptions);
        //###########################################################################
        const renderOptions = {
            useIdBufferSelection: true,
            webglInitParams: {
                canvas: null,
                antialias: false,
                alpha: true,
                premultipliedAlpha: true,
                preserveDrawingBuffer: true,
                stencil: false,
                depth: true
            }
        };
        viewer.initialize(renderOptions);
        viewer.setProfile(new Autodesk.Viewing.Profile(profileSettings));
        viewer.setBackgroundOpacity(0);
        viewer.setGroundShadowAlpha(/**@type{float}*/1); // cast to non-existent "float" type because the viewer3D.js developers require it
        viewer.setGroundShadowColor(new THREE.Color(0, 0, 0));
        viewer.setGroundShadow(profileSettings.settings.groundShadow);
        viewer.setSelectionMode(Autodesk.Viewing.SelectionMode.LEAF_OBJECT);
        (function () {
            // make the background of the canvas and all parent elements up to the container transparent
            let Elem = viewer.canvas;
            while (Elem !== viewerContainerDiv) {
                Elem.style.backgroundColor = "transparent";
                Elem.style.backgroundImage = "none";
                Elem = Elem.parentNode;
            }
        })();

        /**
         * @param {{x:number,y:number,z:number,rotation:number,scaleX:number,scaleY:number,scaleZ:number}} [placement]
         * @param {function(model:Autodesk.Viewing.Model|RenderModel,fragList:FragmentList|FragList):void} [onLoad]
         */
        function GetModelOptions(placement, onLoad) {
            placement ??= {x: 0, y: 0, z: 0, rotation: 0, scaleX: 1, scaleY: 1, scaleZ: 1};
            __isFunction(onLoad ??= () => undefined) || __err("onLoad must be a function");
            let totalFragmentsReceived = 0;

            /**
             * @param {Autodesk.Viewing.Model|RenderModel} model
             * @param {number} geomId
             * @param {number[]} fragIndexes
             */
            function onMeshReceived(model, geomId, fragIndexes) {
                totalFragmentsReceived += fragIndexes.length;
                const fragList =/**@type{FragmentList|FragList}*/model.getFragmentList();
                const totalFragmentsExpected = fragList.fragments.fragId2dbId.length;
                totalFragmentsReceived === totalFragmentsExpected && onLoad(model, fragList);
            }

            /**
             * @param {?{x:number,y:number,z:number,rotation:number,scaleX:number,scaleY:number,scaleZ:number}} o
             * @return {LmvMatrix4}
             */
            function GetPlacementTransform(o) {
                __isObject(o) || __err("o must be an object");
                __isNumber(o.x) || __err("o.x must be a number");
                __isNumber(o.y) || __err("o.y must be a number");
                __isNumber(o.z) || __err("o.z must be a number");
                __isNumber(o.rotation) || __err("o.rotation must be a number");
                __isNumber(o.scaleX) || __err("o.scaleX must be a number");
                __isNumber(o.scaleY) || __err("o.scaleY must be a number");
                __isNumber(o.scaleZ) || __err("o.scaleZ must be a number");
                const TransformMatrix = new THREE.Matrix4().setPosition(new THREE.Vector3(o.x, o.y, o.z));
                const RotationMatrix = new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationZ(o.rotation);
                const ScaleMatrix = new THREE.Matrix4().makeScale(o.scaleX, o.scaleY, o.scaleZ);
                return TransformMatrix.multiply(new THREE.Matrix4().multiplyMatrices(RotationMatrix, ScaleMatrix));
            }

            return {
                createWireframe: false,
                disable3DModelLayers: true,
                disablePrecomputedNodeBoxes: true,
                keepCurrentModels: true,
                loadAsHidden: false,
                loadInstanceTree: true,
                onMeshReceived: onMeshReceived,
                placementTransform: GetPlacementTransform(placement),
                globalOffset: {x: 0, y: 0, z: 0},
                packNormals: true,
                preserveView: false,
                skipExternalIds: true,
                skipHiddenFragments: true,
                skipPrefs: true,
                underlayRaster: false,
                useConsolidation: false,
            };
        }

        const models =/**@type{(Autodesk.Viewing.Model|RenderModel)[]}*/[];
        const fragLists =/**@type{(FragmentList|FragList)[]}*/[];

        function TryFinishLoading(model, fragList) {
            models.push(model);
            fragLists.push(fragList);
            models.length === 3 && OnFullyLoaded(viewer, models, fragLists);
        }

        const url = "variety001/output.svf";
        viewer.loadModel(url, GetModelOptions({x: 0, y: -40, z: 0, rotation: 0, scaleX: 1, scaleY: 1, scaleZ: 1}, function (model, fragList) {
            TryFinishLoading(model, fragList);
        }), () => undefined, function () {
            console.error("could not load model");
        });
        viewer.loadModel(url, GetModelOptions({x: 0, y: 40, z: 0, rotation: 0, scaleX: 1, scaleY: 1, scaleZ: 1}, function (model, fragList) {
            TryFinishLoading(model, fragList);
        }), () => undefined, function () {
            console.error("could not load model");
        });
        viewer.loadModel(url, GetModelOptions({x: 0, y: 0, z: 0, rotation: 0, scaleX: 1, scaleY: 1, scaleZ: 1}, function (model, fragList) {
            TryFinishLoading(model, fragList);
        }), () => undefined, function () {
            console.error("could not load model");
        });
    });

    /**
     * @param {Autodesk.Viewing.GuiViewer3D} viewer
     * @param {(Autodesk.Viewing.Model|RenderModel)[]} models
     * @param {(FragmentList|FragList)[]} fragLists
     */
    function OnFullyLoaded(viewer, models, fragLists) {
        const MatMan =/**@type{MaterialManager}*/viewer.impl.matman();
        MatMan.defaultMaterial.packedNormals = true;
        const LmvMaterialButton = document.getElementById("LmvMaterialButton");
        const ShaderMaterialButton = document.getElementById("ShaderMaterialButton");
        const customMaterial = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
            vertexShader: `#include <pack_normals>\nvoid main() {\ngl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(position.xyz, 1.0);\n}`,
            fragmentShader: `#include <id_decl_frag>\nuniform vec3 color;\nvoid main() {\ngl_FragColor = vec4(color, 1.0);\n#include <final_frag>\n}`,
            uniforms: {color: {type: 'v3', value: new THREE.Vector3(0.5, 0, 0)}}
        });
        customMaterial.needsUpdate = true;
        MatMan.addNonHDRMaterial(__randomInt().toString(), customMaterial);
        LmvMaterialButton.onclick = function () {
            for (const fragList of fragLists) {
                const fragIds = Object.keys(fragList.fragments.fragId2dbId);
                fragIds.forEach(x => fragList.setMaterial(x, MatMan.defaultMaterial));
            }
            viewer.impl.invalidate(true);
        };
        ShaderMaterialButton.onclick = function () {
            for (const fragList of fragLists) {
                const fragIds = Object.keys(fragList.fragments.fragId2dbId);
                fragIds.forEach(x => fragList.setMaterial(x, customMaterial));
            }
            viewer.impl.invalidate(true);
        };
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for providing all the information for your question in such detail.

> I would expect using a `THREE.ShaderMaterial` would have no issues in the Forge Viewer, since the Viewer's `StandardSurface` and `Prism` materials are based on `THREE.ShaderMaterial`.

I don't think this is a correct assumption. Yes, the shaders used in the viewer are based on `THREE.ShaderMaterial`, however they're quite complex as they include different kinds of features, for example, sectioning or ID buffer for picking (which I think explains why the hover and box selection isn't behaving as expected).

Unfortunately the implementation of the shaders in the viewer is not publicly documented, so you would basically have to reverse-engineer one of the existing materials (e.g., the `StandardSurface`), and add the same features to your shader.